# Titanium iOS gives couldn't find module for a controller

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium

I've created an app that logs in via Facebook (Mind you, this all works in android.) And the moment he or she is logged in, you go to the "where" screen using `Alloy.createController("where", {}).getView();` and in the where controller it says: `$.where.open();` The app works flawless on android. But the moment I log in on iOS it shows me a red screen saying APPLICATION ERROR - couldn't find module: alloy/controllers/where for architecture: i386. Does anyone know how to solve this?

So just for clarification, I call the where controller in
index.js using

```
$.index.close();
Alloy.createController('where', {}).getView();
```

and in where.js

```
$.where.open();
```

Comment: try `Alloy.createController('where', {}).getView().open();` in *index.js* and remove `$.where.open();` from *where.js*.

Answer (score 0):

try using the actual window/view id to open or get the view and open that in the controller?

```
// in where.js
$.getView().open()
```